# Error uploading notarized macOS VPN application using system extension network packet tunnel

Tags: macos, vpn, networkextension

I'm currently working on developing a VPN application for macOS that utilizes a system extension network packet tunnel. However, when I try to archive the program and upload it to the notary service, I encounter the following error:

[image]

I want to mention that I have already manually signed the framework, so it seems like there might be another issue causing this problem.

Could anyone provide insights into why I might be facing this error and how I can successfully upload the notarized macOS VPN application with a system extension network packet tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ditto?

```
/usr/bin/ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent "$APP_PATH" "$ZIP_PATH"
```